# I want to create a crime a new column in my data frame that is the crime rate of each specific row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a crime data set, I already calculated the crimes committed in each location. Now I want to create a new column that is the crime rate for that specific row. I already calculated the crime rate now I want to match the specific crime rate to correct row matching the same latitude value

Here I have a loop that creates the crime rate per location. but now i want to get the crime rate value create a new column that matches the latitude in my for loop with my dataframe and adds to corresponding crime rate in each individual row

```
z = ['lat'] 
for i in z:
    print((df[i].value_counts()/1250000)*100000)
32.715973    112.56
32.715738     90.32
32.706341     83.28
32.545300     79.52
32.745903     78.32
32.769389     65.52
32.809860     63.44
32.706287     63.04
32.591684     55.68
32.764136     55.44
32.749983     52.16
32.545291     49.04
32.712584     47.20
32.746868     46.32
32.796864     44.40
32.706287     43.76
32.768120     42.64
32.794497     41.52
32.703369     40.80
32.714797     40.40
32.716977     39.44
32.738989     39.04
32.755182     37.28
32.957955     35.52
32.759375     35.28
32.565237     34.72
32.739964     34.08
32.767116     34.00
32.877050     32.24
32.706559     32.24
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can using `transform`

```
df['Newcol']=(df.groupby('lat')['lat'].transform('count')/1250000)*100000
```

---

For loop

```
z = ['lat'] 
for i in z:
    df[i+'col']=(df.groupby(i)[i].transform('count')/1250000)*100000
```

Comment: @DavidArriaga you just need to assign it back

Comment: do i need a for loop ?

Comment: @DavidArriaga you only have one row need to adjust why you need for loop

Comment: @DavidArriaga and I have adding the for loop

Comment: ok perfect it actually worked without the for loop thank you so much